# Eloquent order model by its relationship hasManyTrough

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables

`products`, `product_categories` and `categories`

`product_categories` is a pivot table that help me on the relationship between `products` & `categories`.

The relation is as follow in `Product.php` model:

```
public function categories() {
 return $this->hasManyThrough(Category::class, ProductCategory::class, 'product_id', 'id', 'id', 'category_id');
}
```

So now I need to query the products so I am doing the following:

```
Product::with('options')
         ->with('options.price')
         ->with('categories')
         ->paginate(25);
```

I can not find the way to sort my products list by the category name on the categories table...

is there any way?

My products table is quite large so it wont be possible to get all the results first and then `sortBy()->take(25);`

EDIT

The categories table has multiple categories and subcategories... the product_categories relate products with only subcategories...
Basically what I want is to sort the products by the main category

Comment: Since it is a hasMany, there is gonna be multiple categories so which is it gonna sort by?

Comment: @mrhn thats a good question... actually I need to update my question please check in a bit... well is to complex, you just make me realize that my question is not completed